# Can I use the word 'soon' in such context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

**Sentence:**

> Thank you for your **soon** response ***(soon response = quick answer)***

I didn't find such way of using the word ['soon'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/soon) but I think that I heard such using somewhere.

**Question:**

> Can I use the word 'soon' in this context *(soon response = quick answer)*?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, **soon** is an adverb not an adjective.  Thank you for replying so soon, or so quickly. "Thank you in advance for a prompt reply."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Soon" is an adverb, not an adjective, so it is used to modify verbs, not nouns.  It would be fine to use with the verb *to respond*:

> Thank you for responding so soon!

Adjectives like "soon":  *quick, prompt, timely, expeditious, speedy*, plus many others.